# How to configure nginx ingress in kubernetes for HTTPS backends with custom CA?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I want to expose an HTTPS K8s service that uses a certificate derived from a custom root CA, outside the cluster using nginx ingress controller. Are the following configurations supported and if yes, how?

1. client -- (HTTP) -- ingress -- (HTTPS) -- k8s service
2. client -- (HTTPS) -- ingress -- (HTTPS) -- k8s service

Is it possible to configure nginx ingress controller such that it can do TLS and mutual-TLS with the HTTPS backend service? 
How do I provision a root certificate for backend server certificate validation to nginx ingress?
Is it possible to do SSL termination on the ingress and do mutual-TLS with the backend?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to provision the backend server certificates using the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-ssl-secret` annotation.